# C language & sigintHandler

Tags: c, pipe, sigkill

I want to delete the FIFO file when I suddenly click "ctrl+c"  . I want to catch that signal and then delete the after before actually killing the process .
here is my code and I don't know what went wrong :

```
 #include <fcntl.h>
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include  <stdlib.h>
 #include <sys/stat.h>
 #include <unistd.h>
 #include <signal.h>
 #define MAX_BUF 512

 void sigintHandler(int sig_num,char * myfifo)
{
puts("hello you there .please don't leave ");
unlink(myfifo);
exit(0);
}

int main()
{

printf("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *\n");
printf("Content-Type: text/event-stream\n\n");
int fd;
char buf[MAX_BUF];

char * myfifo = "/tmp/omcipipe";
struct stat st;
```

//catch ctrl c

```
 sigaction(SIGINT, sigintHandler);



  //Create FIFO file 
     if (stat(myfifo, &st) != 0)
     mkfifo(myfifo, 0666);

 fd = open(myfifo, O_RDONLY);
while (read(fd, buf, MAX_BUF)>0)
{
    printf("data: %s", buf);
    printf("\n");
    fflush(stdout);
} 

puts( "----closing----"); 
close(fd);
unlink(myfifo);
return 0;
```

}

Comment: For one, you can't safely call functions that aren't async-signal-safe in a signal handler.  Assuming Linux, [`puts()` and `exit()` are not async-signal-safe](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html).

Comment: `void sigintHandler(int sig_num,char * myfifo)` is not valid, only an `int` (the signal number) is passed.

Comment: Read [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) & [signal-safety(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html). FIFOs and signals are operating system specific. You probably need some `linux` or `POSIX` tag

Comment: And enable your compiler warnings - and pay attention to them.  `sigaction(SIGINT, sigintHandler);` is even more wrong that I noticed at first - `sigaction()` is passed a signal number and two `struct sigaction *` values, not a signal number and a `void (*handler)(int)` signal handler function directly.

Comment: So I get from your comment is that I should not use "sigintHandler" in order for me to delete my FIFO file ? @Basile Starynkevitch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly your way of setting a signal handler using `sigaction()` is not correct as you didn't fill all the member of `struct sigaction`. Fill all required member

```
struct sigaction info;
info.sa_handler = sigintHandler;
sigaction(SIGINT,&info,NULL);
```

Secondly, to read data from `fifo` file *while loop* is not required as you are reading `MAX_BUF` at a time. Loop is not required, read like this

```
int ret = read(fd, buf, MAX_BUF);
buf[ret-1] = '\0'; /*it should be null terminated */
```

Thirdly, `sigintHandler()` excepts only one argument. From the manual page of `sigaction()`

```
struct sigaction {
        void     (*sa_handler)(int);  /*handler expects only 1 argument */
        /* other member */
}
```

Finally & most importantly it is not safe to call functions like `printf()` & `exit()` from within a signal handler.

your `sigHandler()` looks like

```
static void sigintHandler(int sig_num) {
        write(1,"in isr\n",strlen("in isr\n"));
        /*  set some flag variable here & use that 
        flag variable in main() function to remove the fifo */
}
```

see this [How to avoid using printf in a signal handler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16891019/how-to-avoid-using-printf-in-a-signal-handler)

Here is the example code

```
static int fifo_flag = 0;
static void sigintHandler(int sig_num) {
        write(1,"in isr\n",strlen("in isr\n"));
        fifo_flag = 1;
}
int main(void){
        printf("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *\n");
        printf("Content-Type: text/event-stream\n\n");
        int fd = 0, index = 0;
        char buf[MAX_BUF];
        #if 0
        char *myfifo = "data";
        #endif
        //char * myfifo = "/tmp/omcipipe";
        struct stat st;
        struct sigaction info;
        info.sa_handler = sigintHandler;
        //info.sa_flags = /* set to defaulgs a/c to your requirement*/

        if (stat(myfifo, &st) != 0) {
                mkfifo(myfifo, 0666);
                perror("mkfifo");
        }
        fd = open(myfifo, O_RDONLY | 0666);
        if(fd == -1){
                perror("open");
                return 0;
        }
        char ch = 0;
        while(read(fd, &ch, 1) > 0) {
                sigaction(SIGINT,&info,NULL);/* if ctrl+c  is called */
                buf[index] = ch;
                //sleep(1);/* just to observe ctrl+c behaviour, not advised to use */
                printf("%c\n",buf[index]);
                index++;
        }
        buf[index] = '\0';
        printf("data: %s", buf);
        printf("\n");
        puts( "----closing----");
        close(fd);
        if(fifo_flag == 1) { /*if flag is set, unlink fifo */
                unlink(myfifo); /* you can unlink fifo file here */
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous problems with your code.

This code assumes `read()` terminates data with a `'\0'` character:

```
while (read(fd, buf, MAX_BUF)>0)
{
    printf("data: %s", buf);
    printf("\n");
    fflush(stdout);
}
```

`read()` merely reads raw bytes and nothing more.  It will not properly terminate strings with a `'\0'` character.  So the `printf()` will almost certainly invoke undefined behavior.

This code

```
sigaction(SIGINT, sigintHandler);
```

is just wrong.  [`sigaction()` takes three parameters](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html):

```
   #include <signal.h>

   int sigaction(int signum, const struct sigaction *act,
                 struct sigaction *oldact);
```

You also can only make [async-signal-safe function calls from within a signal handler](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html).  This code

```
 void sigintHandler(int sig_num,char * myfifo)
{
puts("hello you there .please don't leave ");
unlink(myfifo);
exit(0);
}
```

calls `puts()` and `exit()`, neither of which are async-signal-safe.

And as noted in the comments, the signal handler code assumes that `myfifo` is passed as the second parameter.  It isn't.  Per [the sigaction man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html) the second parameter is a `struct siginfo *` that contains information regarding the signal context - but only if the `struct sigaction` passed to the `sigaction()` call that registered the signal handler had the `SA_SIGINFO` flag set, and the handler set using the `sa_sigaction` member instead of the `sa_handler` member.

Comment: How does `char * myfifo` get passed into the signal handler?

Comment: @cdarke Good catch.  I didn't notice that problem in the code.